# Are Pinyin, Chinese, or Latin domain names most appealing to Chinese users?

Tags: domains, internationalization, idn

I'm interested in obtaining a domain to catch the attention of Chinese people, but i have some doubts.

What are the best domain names to catch the attention of Chinese speaking and reading people? A domain in Pinyin, in Chinese characters, or even in Latin characters? And, if you have the site name in Pinyin, is it worth it to hold the same domain name in Chinese characters?

Comment: Why not just buy both of them and just see which ones is used more? Hard factual data would beat any generic prediction